# After moving from JAVA 8 to JAVA 11, the service does not start

Tags: java, linux

There was a service written in Java and compiled earlier under 8. I raised the version to 11 and everything was recompiled without problems, I ran it through tests and nothing fell.

I deploy all this on a PC with Linux, but the service does not start and hangs in the state:

> Active: activating (start)

the service file has the following description:

> [Unit] Description=Blah Blah Blah After=syslog.target
>
> [Service] SyslogIdentifier=%p WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/%p
>
> ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-11/bin/java -server
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx256m -Dconfig.file=/usr/local/%p/app.conf -jar app/$(ls app|head -1)" User=root Restart=on-failure Type=notify NotifyAccess=main
> SuccessExitStatus=143
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

I don't see any errors in the service logs.

If you open the log: `sudo journalctl -xe`, then there are such mentions:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/local/blablaservice/a
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Well, in theory, it should not break anything for me...

I tried to run it locally in IDEA under Windows, but also no errors flew out...

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the output of `java -version` on your deployment machine?

Comment: @Bohemian java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode) .

Comment: There’s your problem. Runtime java must be same or later than build version.

Comment: @Bohemian But I specify a later version in ExecStart...

Comment: Post details as edits to the Question rather than as Comment.

Comment: @iluxa1810 I don't know what ExecStart is, but I do know your java 11 compiled program will not run using a java 8 JRE.